# is it correct in grammar to compare a plural noun to a singular noun?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, comparative-constructions

For example, "their salaries are higher than mine". Is this sentence grammatically correct? Or we have to say "each of their salaries is higher than mine"?

Answer (score 7):

No need to make English harder than it is already.  There is no rule prohibiting comparing groups of things with individual things.

There are some cases where comparing a group to an individual can create an ambiguous statement: *those five people have more money than I do*.  Does this mean that each of the five people has more money than I do, or that the sum of the five people's money is greater than the amount of money I have?  There's no way to tell without more context.

We could remove the ambiguity by using a form like the one you suggested at the end of the question: *each of those five people has more money than I do*.  This is not any more grammatical (because the first was perfectly grammatical), but it is less ambiguous.